# Is it possible to have a custom photo/profile picture on a Postfix mail server?

Tags: linux, debian, email, postfix

Something like the example pictured below would be what I am looking for (the little cup of coffee to the left of the sender name and email) I couldn't find any information anywhere, ideally id like to set this per user.

> [image: Screenshot.]

Comment: Based on what I know, nope. The purpose of Postfix is to be an MTA (mail transport agent) and not anything else. The icon you see in your screenshot is an icon associated with a user account on the email system you are using. Like I will assume that is a Google screenshot: When you have a Google account that account will be associated with all of the services associated with your Google account. So that icon is not simply something connected to your Gmail account but the account in general. To implement something like that you would need to use a mail GUI/account system with that capabilities.